# How are the exact width integer types implemented in GCC?

Tags: c

For example, of my implementation defined a char as 1 byte, then is it just

typedef int8_t char;

In stdint.h, or is there an actual memory manipulation going on?

Comment: Exact width integer types are not guaranteed to be present if the system doesn't support them. Use the *int_leastN_t* versions instead. That being said the implementation most likely uses conditional compilation to decide what each typedef will be for each supported system.

Comment: What is it that doesn't support them? Is it the os or the compiler or the chip or?  My personal project is to re code the entire c standard library, so I guess it's up to me to choose?

Comment: The standard requires them to be typedefs (if they exist, that is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system stdint.h can make assumptions about the architecture and knows things like the size of a short or int. `/usr/include/stdint.h` on macOS is very easy to read. Here's the relevant bit.

```
/* 7.18.1.1 Exact-width integer types */
#include <sys/_types/_int8_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_int16_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_int32_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_int64_t.h>

#include <_types/_uint8_t.h>
#include <_types/_uint16_t.h>
#include <_types/_uint32_t.h>
#include <_types/_uint64_t.h>

/* 7.18.1.2 Minimum-width integer types */
typedef int8_t           int_least8_t;
typedef int16_t         int_least16_t;
typedef int32_t         int_least32_t;
typedef int64_t         int_least64_t;
typedef uint8_t         uint_least8_t;
typedef uint16_t       uint_least16_t;
typedef uint32_t       uint_least32_t;
typedef uint64_t       uint_least64_t;
```

You can dig into each individual header file and look at the typedef. Looking through each of them, they're very simple.

```
typedef __signed char           int8_t;
typedef short                   int16_t;
typedef int                     int32_t;
typedef long long               int64_t;
```

And `uint*_t` are just unsigned versions of that.

---

Since gcc is not the system compiler on a Mac, that's clang, it cannot make assumptions about the architecture, so it uses the existing stdint.h. Here's gcc's stdint.h. It loads the system stdint.h, plus its own header to add its own non-standard things.

```
$ cat /opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0/include/stdint.h 
#ifndef _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#if __STDC_HOSTED__
# if defined __cplusplus && __cplusplus >= 201103L
#  undef __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  undef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
# endif
# include_next <stdint.h>
#else
# include "stdint-gcc.h"
#endif
#define _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#endif
```